# AVCapture Session To Capture Image SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession

I have created an AVCaptureSession to capture video output and display it to the user via UIView. Now I want to be able to click a button (takePhoto method) and display the image from the session in an UIImageView. I have tried to iterate through each devices connection and try to save the output but that hasnt worked. The code I have is below

```
let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
var stillImageOutput: AVCaptureStillImageOutput!

@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var cameraView: UIView!


// If we find a device we'll store it here for later use
var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    super.viewDidLoad()
    println("I AM AT THE CAMERA")
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetLow
    self.captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    if(captureDevice != nil){
        beginSession()
    }
}
    func beginSession() {

    self.stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
    self.captureSession.addOutput(self.stillImageOutput)
    var err : NSError? = nil
    self.captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: self.captureDevice, error: &err))

    if err != nil {
        println("error: \(err?.localizedDescription)")
    }

    var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession)
    self.cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    previewLayer?.frame = self.cameraView.layer.frame
    captureSession.startRunning()
}

@IBAction func takePhoto(sender: UIButton) {
    self.stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(self.stillImageOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) { (buffer:CMSampleBuffer!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
        var image = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(buffer)
        var data_image = UIImage(data: image)
        self.imageView.image = data_image
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Getting this error now                                                                        `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** Cannot add output <AVCaptureStillImageOutput: 0x1742221c0> to capture session <AVCaptureSession: 0x17000ae70 [AVCaptureSessionPresetLow]>
    <AVCaptureDeviceInput: 0x174221840 [Back Camera]> -> <AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x1742217e0>
    <AVCaptureDeviceInput: 0x174221840 [Back Camera]> -> <AVCaptureStillImageOutput: 0x174221da0> because more than one output of the same type is unsupported.'`

Comment: Start by taking out the line: captureSession.addOutput(self.stillImageOutput) and see where you're add. That should fix the error.

Comment: @user3353890 i fixed the error (I updated the above code) but now I am only getting a static image for my preview instead of the video from the camera...?

Comment: what do you mean by static image?

Comment: @user3353890 the cameraview is not displaying the video the camera is capturing but rather is just set to whatever static image the camera first captures when the capturesession starts running.

Comment: hmm, that's strange...give me a few mins, i'll get back to you.

Comment: I don't know if this is affecting anything, but make sure you set your previewLayer.frame before you add it as a sublayer in your begin session method.

Comment: also, remove addOutput from your beginSession() you don't need it

Comment: When i remove addOutput it crashes on me. Should I keep the code you posted below when i remove it?

Comment: yes, I would try that

Comment: ok now it all works except I am getting video connection is equal to nil so it is not able to capture the image. Any idea why?

Comment: take a look at my answer below, that should set it all up for you to work....it worked for me when I tried it. You might need to change the previewLayer variables around some to fit what you have in your app, but that should be easy.

Comment: ok great i will try it out! One quick thing...where is videoCaptureDevice defined in setupVideoRecorder?

Comment: Also where is videoInput used again?

Comment: @user3353890 thanks for all the help I really appreciate it. I got it to work by implementing the below added solution.

Comment: you're welcome, sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should try adding a new thread when adding input and outputs to the session before starting it. In Apple's documentation they state

> Important: The startRunning method is a blocking call which can take some time, therefore you should perform session setup on a serial queue so that the main queue isn't blocked (which keeps the UI responsive). See AVCam for iOS for the canonical implementation example.

Try using a dispatch in the create session method such as below

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), { // 1
        self.captureSession.addOutput(self.stillImageOutput)
        self.captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: self.captureDevice, error: &err))
        self.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
        if err != nil {
            println("error: \(err?.localizedDescription)")
        }
        var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession)
        previewLayer?.frame = self.cameraView.layer.bounds
        previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { // 2
                    // 3
            self.cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
            self.captureSession.startRunning()
            });
        });
```