# Unable to add output for iOS custom camera

Tags: ios, swift, camera, output

Up until recently, my custom camera was working fine. However, I have recently been receiving an error (perhaps with the upgrade to Xcode 8.2 and 8.2.1). I have the following code for loading the camera:

```
func reload() {


    captureSession?.stopRunning()
    previewLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    captureSession!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

    let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withDeviceType: .builtInWideAngleCamera, mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, position: direction)

    var input = AVCaptureDeviceInput()

    do {
        input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
    } catch {
        print("error")
        return
    }

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
        if self.captureSession!.canAddInput(input) == true {
            self.captureSession!.addInput(input)

            if self.captureSession!.canAddOutput(self.cameraOutput) {
                self.captureSession!.addOutput(self.cameraOutput)
                self.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession)
                self.previewLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                self.previewLayer!.connection?.videoOrientation = .portrait
                self.previewLayer?.frame = self.bounds
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer!)
                    self.captureSession!.startRunning()
                    self.clickedImage = nil
                    self.bringSubview(toFront: self.rotateButton)
                }
            } else {
                print("cannot add ouput")
            }
        } else {
            print("cannot add input")
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.bringSubview(toFront: self.rotateButton)
        }


    }

}
```

For some reason, it keeps print "cannot add output" in the debug logs. I have tried to resolve this using [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930699/avcapture-session-to-capture-image-swift), but it still does not run properly. Does anyone know what this means and how to fix it? Thanks!