# Cannot add Output because more than one output of the same type is unsupported

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, xcode11.5

I am a beginner at Swift, using Swift 5 and XCode 11.5 This is my code for creating my camera. I hope it's enough!

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    setupCaptureSession()
    setupDevice()
    setupInputOutput()
    setupPreviewLayer()
    captureSession.startRunning()
}
   
func setupCaptureSession() {
    captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
}

func setupDevice() {
    let deviceDiscoverySession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: AVCaptureDevice.Position.unspecified)
    let devices = deviceDiscoverySession.devices
    
    for device in devices {
        if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back {
            backCamera = device
        } else if device.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.front {
            frontCamera = device
        }
    }
    currentDevice = backCamera
}

func setupInputOutput() {
    do {
        
        let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: currentDevice!)
        if let inputs = captureSession.inputs as? [AVCaptureDeviceInput] {
            for input in inputs {
                captureSession.removeInput(input)
            }
        }
        captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)
        photoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
        photoOutput!.setPreparedPhotoSettingsArray([AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecType.jpeg])], completionHandler: nil)
        captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput!)
        
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}

func setupPreviewLayer() {
    self.cameraPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    self.cameraPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    self.cameraPreviewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
    self.cameraPreviewLayer?.frame = view.frame
    
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(self.cameraPreviewLayer!, at: 0)
}


@IBAction func rotateCamera(_ sender: Any) {
    captureSession.beginConfiguration()
    
    // Change the device based on the current camera
    let newDevice = (currentDevice?.position == AVCaptureDevice.Position.back) ? frontCamera : backCamera
    
    // Remove all inputs from the session
    for input in captureSession.inputs {
        captureSession.removeInput(input as! AVCaptureDeviceInput)
    }
    
    // Change to the new input
    let cameraInput:AVCaptureDeviceInput
    do {
        cameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: newDevice!)
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return
    }
    
    if captureSession.canAddInput(cameraInput) {
        captureSession.addInput(cameraInput)
    }
    
    currentDevice = newDevice
    captureSession.commitConfiguration()
}
```

I am trying to create a camera using AVFoundation but I am getting an error that says:
Thread 1: Exception: "*** -[AVCaptureSession addOutput:] Cannot add output <AVCapturePhotoOutput: 0x283584560> to capture session <AVCaptureSession: 0x2837fc560 [AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto]>\n\t<AVCaptureDeviceInput: 0x2835aa460 [Back Camera]>[vide] -> <AVCapturePhotoOutput: 0x283592a60>\n\t<AVCaptureDeviceInput: 0x2835aa460 [Back Camera]>[vide] -> <AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer: 0x283594bc0> because more than one output of the same type is unsupported"

So I looked online and I found this post: [AVCapture Session To Capture Image SWIFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930699/avcapture-session-to-capture-image-swift) that mentioned a similar error, but because it was using an old version I tried to recreate it. However, the furthest I was able to get was this:

```
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async { // 1
            self.captureSession.addOutput(self.photoOutput!)
            try self.captureSession.addInput( AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: self.currentDevice!))

//supposed to add error here but couldn't do it
                self.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
            var previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession)
                previewLayer.frame = self.cameraView.layer.bounds
//In my project it said there was no member cameraView of UIViewController. 
                previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
            DispatchQueue.main.async { // 2
                        // 3
                self.cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
                self.captureSession.startRunning()
                }
            }
```

Since many methods have been deprecated since then, I had a hard time finding new ones, and I wasn't even able to add the error as an argument as it was an extra argument in the call. I would really appreciate it if someone could help me figure out how to fix this issue of multiple inputs. I tried my hardest to do so, but I honestly couldn't find any solutions.

Thank you!

Edit: I added some more code.

Edit 2: For anyone who was following, the problem was that I called them in view did appear making the outputs show several times thanks to the help of Matt (in the comments). I fixed it by using view did load

Comment: You're not showing enough code. From the error message, which is complaining about "more than one output", it sounds like you are configuring your capture session more than once. But without knowing more about the capture session, what else you say to it, and how `inputOutput` is called, it's hard to say anything.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your reply. I added the rest of this code. I hope it's enough.

Comment: `viewDidAppear` can be called many times. So in that case you are running that code each time...

Comment: Then how exactly would I fix that? Should I move the methods from view did appear to view did load? Thank you!

Comment: You could. Or just look at the session and don’t initialize it if you’ve already initialized it.

Answer (score 1):

Before you call `addOutput:`,you you should check `canAddOutput:`.Because, calling `addOutput:` too many times will lead to a crash.

Answer (score 1):

working in swift 5.7, iOS 16.0

```
if session.canAddOutput(videoDataOutput) {
        session.addOutput(videoDataOutput)
       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above solutions don't work, please remove the the *input* and *output* from the capture session before each session or in viewWillDisappear.

```
captureSession.removeInput(input)
captureSession.removeOutput(captureMetadataOutput)
```

When new session starts, input and output will be added again.